# Is it possible to make my own firebase password email link

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, admin

I have an issue with using Firebase auth. I have a main user who needs to create other users, but the problem is that once an account is created, the password is no longer visible after the application is closed. I had the idea of sending an email password reset for each new user, but there are only 150 requests allowed per day. Can I use my SMTP server to handle this and have unlimited requests? I have my backend on ASP.NET, so would it be better to move the entire user authentication process there?

I tried sending password reset emails each time for new user, but there are only 150 request allowed per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creation of a new user's account on Firebase Authentication should be left to that user themselves. Pre-creating accounts is an anti-pattern.

The recommended approach is to send a normal invite link through your regular email server for the users to create an account on your app, something that doesn't involve Firebase at all. Then each user who clicks the link can sign-up themselves, set their password on sign-up, and you won't hit the quota limit.

If you want to restrict who can sign up to your app, have a look at the documentation on [blocking Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions), which contains this example of limiting signup to a specific domain:

```js
exports.beforeCreate = functions.auth.user().beforeCreate((user, context) => {
  // (If the user is authenticating within a tenant context, the tenant ID can be determined from
  // user.tenantId or from context.resource, e.g. 'projects/project-id/tenant/tenant-id-1')

  // Only users of a specific domain can sign up.
  if (user.email.indexOf('@acme.com') === -1) {
    throw new functions.auth.HttpsError('invalid-argument', `Unauthorized email "${user.email}"`);
  }
});
```

You can modify this to fit your needs, for example make it work from a list of allowed email addresses (the people who are currently trying to pre-create accounts for).

Comment: The pre-creating is security mesure. But the invite link is better.  Is this invitation link is will redirect user to web app to sign up? Can you give me example of good invitation link